# Ingesting HDF5 data: keys within keys, getting data into arrays

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I need some help.

I have an HDF5 file containing spectrum data (time, frequencies, and the power level of a given frequency at a given time). Here is how the file structured (using HDFView):

[HDFView of Data File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UZZS.png)

The main groups (keys) are the HOURS, and then inside are the minutes, with each minute being its own group (key). Data was collected at 0.02 seconds for 60 seconds... so there are 3000 rows...and the frequency bins are 256 (i.e. start at 1MHz and end at 26MHz, spaced into 256 spacing apart. For example.e. 23 --> 23:10 --> 2D array of the power

```
0           0           1           2       .....           255
1       -53.672386  -53.82235   -53.773468  .....        -50.566887
2       -53.85694   -53.945183  -53.63385   .....        -51.306465   
3       -53.709038  -53.55101   -53.55305   .....        -52.7324906
.
.
.
2999    -53.23989   -51.501495  -50.681602              -52.227474
```

I am able to access the individual minutes data and pull them into arrays and then plot the data. Like this:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read in the HDF5 file
file = h5py.File("/home/tom/Desktop/2021-10-28_ch0.hdf5", 'r')

# Search for the main groups in the file. The main groups are hours: 20, 22, etc...

# Select one of the hours (i.e. 23)
hour = file['23']

# Search for the subgroups (keys) within the chosen hour. There are "hour:minutes" i.e. 23:10
#for key in hour.keys():
    #print( key )

# Select key with data for minutes 10, 11, 12, 13 and save into individual arrays:
minute_data_10=hour['23:10'][()]
minute_data_11=hour['23:11'][()]
minute_data_12=hour['23:12'][()]
minute_data_13=hour['23:13'][()]

# Generate a 1D array of TIME spanning 4 minutes (because we ingested
# 4x 1 minute slices of data:

time = np.linspace(0, 60*4, 3000*4)

# Generate a 1D array of FREQUENCY
frequency = np.linspace(1.575E0, 26.82402336E0, 256)

# Combine minute_data_10  minute_data_11 minute_data_12 and minute_data_13 along the time axis (axis=0)
comb_min = np.concatenate( (minute_data_10, minute_data_11, minute_data_12, minute_data_13), axis=0 )

print( comb_min.shape )

# Plot the data
im = plt.pcolormesh(frequency, time, comb_min, cmap='jet')
plt.colorbar(im).ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)
plt.title('Spectrum')
plt.ylabel('Seconds ago...')
#plt.xlabel('frequency in Hz')
im.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
plt.show()
```

[Spectrum Plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLHln.png)

I am manually defining each minute (min 10, 11, 12, 13) combining them and then plotting them.

BUT...what I would like to do is to automatically ingest ALL minutes for ALL hours of my choosing and then plot it into one plot. For example, how can I ingest ALL minutes in hour 15 and then plot the spectrum ? OR, how could I plot the first 5 hours of the data ?

Comment: just loop over all the keys per hour, or loop over all hours and keys within those hours that you choose

Comment: Yup, tried this and it works well (still learning Python though). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDF5 files are self-describing. (In other words, you can get the group or dataset names from the file -- you don't have to know them in advance.) As noted above, you do this with the `.keys()` method. (Note: h5py objects are NOT dictionaries; h5py simply uses Python's *dictionary syntax* to access the names.)

Using the keys/names has the additional benefit of only reading existing datasets. Looking at your image, there are datasets for time `15:00` and `15:02` but not for `15:01`. (This gap has additional implications when creating your plot --- but that's a different problem.)

Code below shows how to do this. It uses the same approach: create a list of h5py objects, then combine into a single array with `np.concatenate`. It also collects the `hh:mm` times (from the dataset names) in a list you can use to create the `time` array.

I used Python's file context manager. This is preferred over open/close methods (avoids leaving files open, and improves readability).

**Simple example (hard coded for ['15'] hour group):**

```
with h5py.File('/home/tom/Desktop/2021-10-28_ch0.hdf5.h5','r') as h5f:  
    times = []
    collect = []
    hh = '15'
    for hhmm in h5f[hh].keys():
        times.append(hhmm)
        collect.append(h5f[hh][hhmm])
    
    comb_min = np.concatenate( collect, axis=0 )
    print(times)
    print(len(collect), comb_min.shape)
```

**More general example (reads all groups[hours] and datasets['hh:mm']):**

```
with h5py.File('/home/tom/Desktop/2021-10-28_ch0.hdf5.h5','r') as h5f:  
    times = []
    collect = []
    for hh in h5f.keys():
        for hhmm in h5f[hh].keys():
            times.append(hhmm)
            collect.append(h5f[hh][hhmm])
    
    comb_min = np.concatenate( collect, axis=0 )
    print(times)
    print( len(collect), comb_min.shape )
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just generalizing what you already have.  To get all of hour 15:

```
hh = '15'
hour = file[hh]

collect = [hour[f'{hh}:{mm:02d}'] for mm in range(60)]
comb_min = np.concatenate( collect, axis=0 )
print( comb_min.shape )
```

To get the first 5 hours:

```
collect = [hours[f'{hh:02d}:{mm:02d}'] for hh in range(5) for mm in range(60)]
comb_min = np.concatenate( collect, axis=0 )
print( comb_min.shape )
```

And it looks like the `for` clauses are backwards, but they're not.

Comment: Verification that each `hh:mm` dataset exists may be required. For example, the image shows `15:00` and `15:02` but not `15:01`.

Comment: I don't see that in the problem statement, but my code will get such verification in the sense that it will trigger a KeyNotFound exception if the record doesn't exist.